# Getting SerializationException despite using custom TypeConverters

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, android-room

I'm making a call to a weather API and getting back the `HourlyResponse` that you see below. The hourly field maps an array of JSON objects to a list of `HourWeatherEntry` entity classes which I'm trying to store using Room. Now, in my RoomDatabase implementation, I've specified the custom type converters to be used for the `List<Weather>` field of the HourWeatherEntry class and despite that, I'm getting the SerializationException that I've pasted below. What am I missing, shouldn't the converters suffice? Why would I also need to define the Weather class' serialization methods for the class itself?

HourlyResponse.kt:

```
data class HourlyResponse(
    val hourly: List<HourWeatherEntry>,
    val lat: Double,
    val lon: Double,
    val timezone: String
)
```

HourWeatherEntry.kt

```
@Entity(tableName = "hour_weather")
data class HourWeatherEntry(
    @SerializedName("weather")
    val weatherInfo: List<Weather>,
    @SerializedName("temp")
    val temperature: Double,
    @SerializedName("dt")
    val time: Long
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id:Int = 0
    var icon: String? = null

    init {
        icon = weatherInfo[0].icon
    }
}
```

Weather.kt:

```
data class Weather(
    val description: String,
    val icon: String,
    val id: Int,
    val main: String
)
```

Converters.kt:

```
class Converters {
    val gson = Gson()

    @TypeConverter
    fun weatherToString(weather: Weather): String = gson.toJson(weather)

    @TypeConverter
    fun weatherFromString(json: String): Weather = gson.fromJson(json, Weather::class.java)

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromWeatherList(value: List<Weather>): String = gson.toJson(value)

    @TypeConverter
    fun toWeatherList(value: String): List<Weather> = Json.decodeFromString(value)
}
```

ForecastDatabase.kt:

```
@Database(
    entities = [CurrentWeatherEntry::class, HourWeatherEntry::class, WeekDayWeatherEntry::class, WeatherLocation::class],
    version = 1
)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class ForecastDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun currentWeatherDao(): CurrentWeatherDao
    abstract fun hourWeatherDao(): HourWeatherDao
    abstract fun weekDayWeatherDao(): WeekDayWeatherDao
    abstract fun weatherLocationDao(): WeatherLocationDao

    // Used to make sure that the ForecastDatabase class will be a singleton
    companion object {
        // Volatile == all of the threads will have immediate access to this property
        @Volatile
        private var instance: ForecastDatabase? = null
        private val LOCK = Any() // dummy object for thread monitoring

        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(LOCK) {
            // If the instance var hasn't been initialized, call buildDatabase()
            // and assign it the returned object from the function call (it)
            instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
        }

        /**
         * Creates an instance of the ForecastDatabase class
         * using Room.databaseBuilder().
         */
        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                ForecastDatabase::class.java, "forecast.db"
            )
                //.addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_3) // specify an explicit Migration Technique
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build()
    }
}
```

Exception log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'Weather' is not found.
    Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.
        at kotlinx.serialization.internal.Platform_commonKt.serializerNotRegistered(Platform.common.kt:91)
        at kotlinx.serialization.internal.PlatformKt.platformSpecificSerializerNotRegistered(Platform.kt:29)
        at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.serializer(Serializers.kt:60)
        at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt.serializer(Unknown Source:1)
        at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.builtinSerializer$SerializersKt__SerializersKt(Serializers.kt:96)
        at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.serializerByKTypeImpl$SerializersKt__SerializersKt(Serializers.kt:84)
        at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.serializer(Serializers.kt:59)
        at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt.serializer(Unknown Source:1)
        at com.nesoinode.flogaweather.model.network.typeconverters.Converters.toWeatherList(Converters.kt:25)
        at com.nesoinode.flogaweather.model.db.dao.HourWeatherDao_Impl$3.call(HourWeatherDao_Impl.java:115)
        at com.nesoinode.flogaweather.model.db.dao.HourWeatherDao_Impl$3.call(HourWeatherDao_Impl.java:99)
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:90)
            ... 3 more
```

Comment: You're using a mixture of `com.google.code.gson` and `kotlinx.serialization` libraries.  The error occurs because `Weather` data class does not have `@Serializable` annotation, it tells you exactly this in the stacktrace - "Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly". Use one deserialiser library or the other but not both unless you have a valid reason - or just prefer confusion. For `Gson` replace `Json.decodeFromString(value)` with : `gson.fromJson<List<Weather>>(value, object : TypeToken<List<Weather>>() {}.type)`.

Comment: @MarkKeen You're correct, this is the problem. I didn't think mixing those two libraries together would cause an issue because I had done the same thing in an older project of mine but no errors occured back then. I'll fix the older project as well. Mind posting your comment as an answer?